# What does Emacs without X support mean?

Tags: emacs

I'm going to install Emacs for Linux Mint. I ran [Synaptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synaptic_(software)) and searched for Emacs and then I saw Emacs24-nox (without X support). What does Emacs without X support mean?

In what ways is it different from the normal Emacs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs with X support is linked with X and thus allows opening in a special window with mouse support, better visuals, custom fonts, more colors, etc.

Emacs can be run in a terminal, so if this is all you need, you should install the `nox` version.

Comment: And what is "X" then? [X Window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System)?

Comment: Yes, X stands for "X Window System".